# What's the right way to add a custom Helper method for unit test suite in Codeception?

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I am trying to add a custom helper method to unit test suite, but when running the test I get `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function` error.

This is what I have so far

1. Adding the method to _support/Helper/Unit.php
2. Running the build command
3. Setup actor in suite.yml
4. Calling the method via the actor
5. Running test

When I run the test I get:

`ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function ExampleTest::__construct(), 0`

_support/Helper/Unit.php:

```php
namespace Helper;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

class Unit extends \Codeception\Module
{
  public function get_hello()
  {
    return 'Hello';
  }
}
```

Test method:

```
public function testMe1(\UnitTester $I)
{
  $hello = $I->get_hello();
  $this->assertEquals(2, $hello);
}
```

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration

#

# Suite for unit (internal) tests.

class_name: UnitTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - Asserts
    - \Helper\Unit
```

Why doesn't testme1() accept any arguments? What step am I missing?

Comment: The purpose of helper methods is to perform actions, result is probably ignored.
If you want to retrieve some data, it would be better to use data provider.

Comment: @Naktibalda noted, thanks. As of now, just trying to figure out various ways to reuse code within the Codeception framework. I tried some actions with other suites it worked, with unit suite, can't call any methods I place inside helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests methods don't get actor passed as a parameter.

You can call them on `$this->tester`, like in [this example](https://codeception.com/docs/05-UnitTests#Testing-Database)

```
function testSavingUser()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setName('Miles');
    $user->setSurname('Davis');
    $user->save();
    $this->assertEquals('Miles Davis', $user->getFullName());

    $this->tester->seeInDatabase('users', ['name' => 'Miles', 'surname' => 'Davis']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @Naktibalda is correct for integration tests, not for unit tests.

Only way i find to get modul methods in unit tests is using getModule() method:

```
public function testSomethink()
{
    $this->getModule('Filesystem')->openFile('asd.js');
}
```

In this way you propably can load custom module too.

If not, and you can reuse some code in unit test, make some parent class for all yout unit tests. Somethink like *BaseUnitTest*, which extends from *Codeception\Test\Unit*. And write your reusable code in this class.